# Sed or replace a line for context in part of line.

Tags: unix, replace, awk, sed

I have millions of  line that looks something like this. I am looking for a way to use replace these lines with what the "TABLENAME" is. "TABLENAME" can be different everytime. "TABLENAME" is always in this line. Basically I'm looking to convert this path to just the Table name. My idea was to look for the 5th occurence of " " and replace the whole line of it with sed. Does sed have this ability ? Thank you in advance.

My line

```
path : /BLAH/BLAH1[(@name="BLAH2")]/BLAH/BLAH[(@BLAH="SERVER")]/BLAH[(@name="CHECK")]/sampler[(@name="SAMPLE")][(@type="")]/table[(@name="TABLENAME")]/rows/row[(@name="AROW")]/cell[(@column="ACELL")]
```

The result I want ( Turn My line to just the line below ) ( I can not use sed replace path to TABLENAME because sometimes it may be a different table name and i don't know which one it may be)

```
TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r "s/.*table\[\(@name=\"([A-Z]+).*/\1/" yourfile
```

I've just made some assumptions. If you'd put more examples maybe I could help you precisely.
Remember that if you want to make the replacement **in-place** you can use the option `--in-place`

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I wanted. You have no idea how easier you made my life.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I fully understood, but consider the following input:

```
path : /BLAH/BLAH1[(@name="BLAH2")]/BLAH/BLAH[(@BLAH="SERVER")]/BLAH[(@name="CHECK")]/sampler[(@name="SAMPLE")][(@type="")]/table[(@name="TABLENAME1")]/rows/row[(@name="AROW")]/cell[(@column="ACELL")]
path : /BLAH/BLAH1[(@name="BLAH2")]/BLAH/BLAH[(@BLAH="SERVER")]/BLAH[(@name="CHECK")]/sampler[(@name="SAMPLE")][(@type="")]/table[(@name="TABLENAME2")]/rows/row[(@name="AROW")]/cell[(@column="ACELL")]
path : /BLAH/BLAH1[(@name="BLAH2")]/BLAH/BLAH[(@BLAH="SERVER")]/BLAH[(@name="CHECK")]/sampler[(@name="SAMPLE")][(@type="")]/table[(@name="TABLENAME3")]/rows/row[(@name="AROW")]/cell[(@column="ACELL")]
path : /BLAH/BLAH1[(@name="BLAH2")]/BLAH/BLAH[(@BLAH="SERVER")]/BLAH[(@name="CHECK")]/sampler[(@name="SAMPLE")][(@type="")]/table[(@name="TABLENAME4")]/rows/row[(@name="AROW")]/cell[(@column="ACELL")]
```

(gnu) awk to the rescue:

```
$ awk -F@ '{ match($7, /"([^"]+)/, arr); print arr[1]}' input.txt
TABLENAME1
TABLENAME2
TABLENAME3
TABLENAME4
```